# Create QTransform given 4 points defining the transformed unit square

Tags: qt, math, geometry, perspective, coordinate-transformation

Given 4 points being be the result of

```
QPolygon poly = transform.mapToPolygon(QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1));
```

how can I find `QTransform transform`? (Even better: also given an arbitrary source rectangle)

*Motivation:* Given the four corner points of an image to be drawn in a perspectively distorted coordinate system, how can I draw the image using QPainter?

[image: Illustration of the problem]

This is a screenshot illustrating the problem in GIMP, where one can transform a layer by moving around the 4 corners of the layer. This results in a perspective transformation. I want to do exactly the same in a Qt application. I know that QTransform is not restricted to affine transformations but can also handle perspective transformations.

Comment: Note: I currently try to solve the problem. I start with p1 (which is the mapped upper left point (0,0)): Therefore I just use an translation matrix. p2 and p3 can be reached by using a scaling and shearing matrix. But I have problems reaching p4: I don't understand the math behind the perspective transformation and thus don't know how the number for the matrix entries in the third column affect the transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `QTransform.squareToQuad`. Just pass it the `QPolygonF` you want to transform to.

I've sometimes had some issues getting squareToQuad to do what I want, and have had to use `QTransform.quadToQuad` instead, defining my own starting quad, but you might have more luck.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. Damn, my whole work with all the math was for nothing... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, which calculates the transformation matrix step by step.

```
// some example points:
QPointF p1(1.0, 2.0);
QPointF p2(2.0, 2.5);
QPointF p3(1.5, 4.0);
QPointF p4(3.0, 5.0);

// define the affine transformation which will position p1, p2, p3 correctly:
QTransform trans;
trans.translate(p1.x(), p1.y());
trans.scale(p2.x() - p1.x(), p3.y() - p1.y());
trans.shear((p3.x() - p1.x()) / trans.m11(), (p2.y() - p1.y()) / trans.m22());
```

Until now, trans describes a parallelogram transformation. Within this paralellogram, I find p4 (relatively) in the next step. I think that this can be done using a direct formula not involving an inversion of trans.

```
// relative position of the 4th point in the transformed coordinate system:
qreal px = trans.inverted().map(p4).x();
qreal py = trans.inverted().map(p4).y();

// this defines the perspective distortion:
qreal y = 1 + (py - 1) / px;
qreal x = 1 + (px - 1) / py;
```

The values `x` and `y` are hard to explain. Given only one of them (the other set to `1`), this defines the relative scaling of `p4` only. But a combination of both x and y perspective transformation, the meaning of x and y are difficult; I found the formulas by trial and error.

```
// and thus the perspective matrix:
QTransform persp(1/y, 0, 1/y-1,
                 0, 1/x, 1/x-1,
                 0, 0, 1);

// premultiply the perspective matrix to the affine transformation:
trans = persp * trans;
```

Some tests showed that this leads to the correct results. However, I did not tested special cases like those where two points are equal or one of them is on the line segment between two others; I think that this solution might break in such situations.

**Therefore, I still search for some direct formulas for the matrix values `m11`, `m12` ... `m33`, given the point coordinates `p1.x()`, `p1.y()` ... `p4.x()`, `p4.y()`.**

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to use QTransform.squareToQuad?

Comment: Aaaaah, thank you very much @dmd, this is exactly what I was looking for, of course. I didn't RTFM enough, or better said, the name of the function was totally not what I expected for such a function which exactly does what I want!